# h2o AutoML use in class imbalance mode

Tags: h2o

i have a usecase of very imbalace data set , i undersampled the training dataset ,
and tried running the automl in h2o, but it gave me great AUC results (over 0.99) but very bad aup_pr results (0.09).
is it related to the imbalance issue ? 
i ran with weight_column option (http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/weights_column.html) 
but it didn't help.
should i use the balance_classes option instead (when i run both options it fails with "h2oFrame is empty" message) .
the train and test are splitted on date time range , and the test dataset has the proper ration between majority and minority classes.

Answer (score 0):

The large difference between AUC and AUCPR is most likely caused, as you suggest, by the class imbalance. You can either try to set `balance_classes = True` or set weights to a column that would weight the minority class more, e.g. taking the inverse of the class frequency. If you have really small number of observations for the minority class, you can try to synthesise more using e.g. [SMOTE](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.1813.pdf).

Comment: tried the balance_classes but still , ROC AUC was 0.99 and the AUCPR was 0.03 .... so or the measurment is problematic or there is something not right with the balance classes, is there a limit to how much it can balance, if the data set is highly imbalance, does it still works ?

Comment: ROC AUC is not a good metric for highly imbalanced classes, so I would recommend not even looking at it. The low AUCPR suggests your model simply does not work well. What exactly is the proportion of the classes? If you have a very rare event/class to detect, you can also consider casting the problem as an anomaly detection. There's Isolation Forest model available in H2O that can do that.